# jmeter internal functions failing BeanSHellInterpreter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I cannot seem to get past the BeanShellInterpreter whenever I try and use __FileToString built-in function in a BeanShell PreProcessor script.  The FileContents variable does get populated, but the script fails and I cannot work with it.  Here is the code and the error messages...

```
try {
Integer count=vars.get("SessionId").length()-5;
vars.put("vAuth", vars.get("v_username") +     vars.get("SessionId").substring(count) + ":" );
log.info("Writing a info message");
   ${__FileToString(C:/tmp/DeltaConnectDemoTool_3_2_0S1_5515/bin/request.txt,,FileContents)};

log.info("Writing a second info message");
}
catch (Throwable ex ) {
    log.error("Failed to do this or that", ex);
}
```

**The Error is**

> 2016/11/17 15:52:18 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: ``try { Integer count=vars.get("SessionId").length()-5; vars.put("vAuth", vars.get . . . '' Encountered ":" at line 5, column 8.
>
> 2016/11/17 15:52:18 WARN  - jmeter.modifiers.BeanShellPreProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval   In file: inline evaluation of: ``try { Integer count=vars.get("SessionId").length()-5; vars.put("vAuth", vars.get . . . '' Encountered ":" at line 5, column 8.

Answer (score 0):

try putting the string path to file in double quotes, like:

```
${__FileToString("C:/tmp/DeltaConnectDemoTool_3_2_0S1_5515/bin/request.txt",,FileContents)};
```

Answer (score 0):

That's why inlining functions or variables into the script body is not recommended. You have 2 alternative options:

1. Use the function in the "Parameters" section. If the functions returns some value you will be able to refer in later in the Beanshell code as `Parameters` or `bsh.args[0]` like:

   [image: Beanshell Parameters]
2. Implement the function in the Beanshell code. In your case it can be [FileUtils.readFileToString()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/) function:

   ```
   String FileContent = org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("request.txt"));
   vars.put("FileContent", FileContent);
   ```

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for some extra information on scripting in JMeter

Comment: I don't think option 1 would work for me as I have multiple files to open (one for each RESTAPI call I plan to make.  Option 2 worked like a charm...thanks!  PS: Where does the documentation say not to use built-in functions in a script body (just in case there are other pointers in there for me)?